# Space movie with alien probe that makes the crew turn homicidal

Tags: story-identification

Made for TV movie about a spaceship on the edge of the solar system that becomes contaminated by an alien probe. The disease makes the crew try to kill each other. Some of the crew are in life support pods, and are transferred to another ship. I can't remember the title.

Comment: When was it aired/when did you watch it?

Answer (score 9):

Could it be [Alien Cargo](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0184197/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_75) (1999) with Jason London?

I watched some of it a while back on YouTube...ends up with two doomed survivors left on the ship.

Comment: Yes! That's it. Thanks it's been driving me nuts trying to remember that title.

Comment: @Rick: If you click on the green checkmark below the voting score, you can accept the answer. It rewards the person who answered it with some points and it marks the question as answered in the database, which improves our store of knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

[Supernova (2000](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0134983/))?
Not a TV movie, but it bears similarity.

> Supernova chronicles the search and rescue patrol of a medical ship in
>   deep space in the early 22nd century and its six-member crew which
>   includes a Captain and Pilot, a co-pilot, a medical officer, a medical
>   technician, a search and rescue paramedic, and a computer technician.
>   When their vessel, the Nightingale 229, answers an emergency distress
>   signal from a comet mining operation in a distant galaxy, the crew
>   soon finds itself in danger from the mysterious young man they rescue,
>   the alien artifact he's smuggled aboard, and the gravitational pull of
>   a giant star about to supernova. The resulting explosion will be the
>   most massive explosion in the universe.

[Wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova_%282000_film%29) with longer summary.

Has an alien artifact that contains "ninth dimensional matter." Karl came into contact with the ninth dimensional matter after recovering the artifact, and it somehow enabled him to acquire super strength, supernatural healing abilities, and made him younger (such that Kaela did not recognize him). Karl murders most of the crew except Kaela, and strands Nick on the mining platform.

The two remaining survivors use a "dimensional stabilization chamber" (aka pod) to survive a dimensional jump. Also has a rescue pod at some point.

Trailer: