# What movie had an AI computer called "Shoshone"?

Tags: story-identification, b-movies

The computer's name wasn't mentioned very often during the movie.
It had a role like "mother" in Alien.

I think the main character was a mid-30s military woman.

This was a cheaply-made b-movie set in the future but I can't remember much plot.

I saw it at the latest in 2015 and would guess I was made after about 2000.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85514/space-movie-with-alien-probe-that-makes-the-crew-turn-homicidal

Comment: Yes. Answer was accepted in a comment there.

Comment: Well it's the same film but the criteria don't overlap in any way.

Comment: @moopet on story-ID, the criteria for dupe-closure is for both answers to be accepted (or in comments), and be the same work, regardless of how the questions overlap. See [this policy on Meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/98028).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the TV movie *[Alien Cargo](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0184197/)* (1999). The computer's name is actually Shoshoni.

[image: Splash iamge for *Alien Cargo*]

> In a time when interplanetary shipping is routine, poor judgment is a fatal error. The crew of the Solar System Shipping shipping vessel number 17 runs in shifts. When the second shift awakens from hyper-sleep almost ten months after their scheduled time, they find the ship badly damaged, off course, and missing the first shift. What's more, it's discovered the first shift killed each other. As the plot unfolds, something truly evil is discovered on-board - humans.

Found with a search for *film computer shoshone*

I can't find a video that's just a trailer, but the full movie is easy to find on YouTube.

Comment: Dammit! Three minutes too late with the same answer ..for what it's worth I'd tracked down the computer voice actor :- Jennifer Congram as Voice of Shoshoni, SSS17 Computer / SSS Communication Central

Comment: @DannyMcG: Honestly, I'm at rep cap, so I'm perfectly fine with retracting mine so that you can get all the points.

Comment: I did that same search quite a lot but didn't come up with anything :)

Comment: Also this means one of my computers has had its hostname spelt wrong for years.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Nah, you're ok, I was playing about .